# get enclosing class instance at macro expansion time

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I've just started playing with macros and wanted to implement a macro from [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html)

```
class Queryable[T] {
 def map[U](p: T => U): Queryable[U] = macro QImpl.map[T, U]
}
object QImpl {
 def map[T: c.WeakTypeTag, U: c.WeakTypeTag]
        (c: Context)
        (p: c.Expr[T => U]): c.Expr[Queryable[U]] = ...
}
```

So i've came up with the following version:

```
class Query[T](val value: T) {
  def map[U](func: T => U): Query[U] = macro Qry.map[T, U]
}

object Qry {
  def map[T: c.WeakTypeTag, U: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(func: c.Expr[T => U]): c.Expr[Query[U]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val q"class Query($value) { ..$body }" = c.enclosingClass
    c.Expr[Query[U]](q"new Query($func($value))")
  }
}
```

But it failes with a `MatchError`, as i understand `enclosingClass` captures it's enclosing class at the call site, which in REPL session is a generated module. So how can i extract `value` field from `Query` class and pass it to `func` expression in def macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `c.prefix`.